# Fazer um contador de palavras em PHP sem usar função

Tags: php, html, html5, string, for

Tenho que fazer um programa que leia uma string e conte quantas palavras essa string tem. No entanto, para isso, eu só posso utilizar as funções substr, strlen ou strtoupper. Fazendo o programa, eu identifiquei dois problemas:

1. ele irá contar os espaços entre as palavras;
2. ele não irá contar a última palavra por estar sem espaço.

Segue o código e espero que tenha ficado claro:

```
<?php
 $f = "ola    mundo   ";
 $len = strlen($f);
 for ($i = 0; $i <=$len; $i++){
     $posicao = substr ($f, $i, 1);

     if($posicao == " "){
        $j++;
     }
   }
 echo 'a frase eh:', $f,' <br> e ela tem ',$j,' palavras';
?>
```

Comment: Poste o código como texto. É melhor pra quem for te ajudar poder reproduzir.

Comment: desculpe. Feito :)

Comment: Esse exercício é para estimular o raciocínio operacional. Visa estimular a dedução e conclusão de premissas assim como a formulação de hipóteses. Se alguém interferir o apresentando uma resposta estará prejudicando o seu aprendizado, pois o objetivo não é a solução e sim o fazer perceber o caminho, ou caminhos quem levam a solução.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Apesar de concordar com você preciso também dar um voto de confiança pro OP. Nem todo mundo aqui já sabe programar ou tem bons professores nos cursos que faz e ficar perdido dando voltas em um exercício é uma sensação horrível. Eu vou considerar que o OP não veio aqui atrás de uma resposta pronta e deixar um post explicando uma ideia básica para resolver o problema. Jefferson, se ficar com alguma dúvida me acione nos comentários da minha resposta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua lógica tá quase ok, contar a quantidade de espaços pode ser um bom início (ainda não está certo) se as frases forem bem formatadas (o próprio caso de teste que você usou não é e mostra que você precisa mais do que isso).

A base da lógica pra resolver este problema é saber quantas separações existem na frase - pra um caso simples, um espaço seguido de carácter é um indício legal de uma separação. É claro que aí não são considerados alguns possíveis corner cases ou erros de digitação/gramática.

Pra não te entregar o exercício pronto vou deixar um pseudocódigo com a ideia. Note que se a frase pode também começar com espaços o algoritmo precisa ser adaptado, mas essa é a base de uma resolução simples.

```py
frase = "ola    mundo, que  dia    bonito   "

qtd_palavras = 0

para cada caracter da frase:
    se caracter_atual == ' ' && proximo_caracter != ' ':
        qtd_palavras += 1

print "A frase é ${frase} e ela tem ${qtd_palavras} palavras"
```

Comment: Nossa eu conseguiiiiiiiiii que massa kkkkkkkk obrigadooo!!!!!! Ainda avancei no código e adicionei outras coisas, obrigado mesmo :)